# Obtaining Values Instead of API Names when Building a DataFlow in Einstein Analytics

Tags: data, dashboard, einstein-analytics, data-export

I am trying to build a dashboard for my company. However, in order to do that I need to create a dataset. One of the fields that I need to draw for my dataset is an object of picklist type, which outputs API names.

I would like to get the user values that you would see in a Salesforce report, but I haven't been able to come up with any way of doing so in the datflow.

I have been trying to use the following SAQL expression inside the dataflow with 
no results

```
toLabel(accountStatus__c)
```

All the previous questions that dealt with a similar problem seems to offer it as the answer, but is not working for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if more details are needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey in order to get any field from user you need to augment the Object with its owner(User/queue) so now you will be able to access user Object also.

extract Object - select all the fields you need from the primary object
extract user - select the picklist field, User name etc from User Dataset
augment Object_User - now join Object and user nodes using OwnerId and user's Id. Right Select the Picklist Field.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any answer on google so here's a way.
It's not dynamic because you have to manually set the labels for the picklist values but it works.
Once your dataset is created, you have to explore it in a new Lens. Then in the Query Mode, you can find the picklist field and by clicking the arrow next to the field, you have the option "Edit Values".

Finnaly, you just have to set the matching values to the api names and it will automatically be applied to dashboards and lenses that use the dataset.